# wp_schedule _event not working

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have had a look at all the other posts about this online but can not get this to work. I have set up some custom times and then a custom schedule but it is just not working. Here is my code.

```
//set up 5 minute schedling and 30 minutes.
function my_cron_schedules($schedules){

        $schedules["5min"] = array(
            'interval' => 300,
            'display' => __('Once every 5 minutes'));


        $schedules["30min"] = array(
            'interval' => 1800,
            'display' => __('Once every 30 minutes'));

    return $schedules;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_schedules');


register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');

function my_activation() {
    if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_5min_event' )) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), '5min', 'my_5min_event');
    }
}

add_action('my_5min_event', 'update_db_every_5mins');

function update_db_every_5mins() {
    // do something every 5 minutes

            $wpdb->insert("XXXXX_coin_data", array(
            "datetime" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            "symbol" => 'QQQ',
            "name" => 'EEEE',
            "price" => 'EEEEEEEEE',
            "market_cap" => 124545,
            "1h_change" => 245345245,
            "24_change" => 452452,
            "7d_change" => 45245245,
            "rank" => 0000000,
        ));
}

//Clear the 5 minute event after it has run
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_deactivation');

function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_5min_event');
}
```

I have used this to see if the event is in the array but it never is and it also never runs.

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r( _get_cron_array() ); echo '</pre>';
```

I wonder if I am missing something? I want to get the event working, so I can swap to the server cron and then wget the /wp-cron.php every 5 minutes. The cron on the server is running every 5 minutes but even running WP cron manually is doing nothing. So I want to fix it so I can then move it to properly be automated.

Comment: From the codex - **"The action will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site, if the scheduled time has passed."**, meaning if you don't reload every five mins or you have no visits AFTER five mins have passed, it will not do anything. It's more reliable to create a proper cronjob to run a WP function than to use WP cron

Comment: This is what I have done, but the problem I face is that the schedule_event is not being triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself after making the realisation that I am calling the

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');
```

As I am not using a plugin and want it to run as part of the fundamental website the scheduled event was never being called as not "plugin" was being switched on.

Removing the hook to activate the function which contains the scheduled event fixed the problem and it is now in the Cron queue by using this to look at it.

```
$cron_jobs = get_option( 'cron' );
var_dump($cron_jobs);
```

Hope this helps someone else who may have similar issues.